# MathJax - Math Process Error while adding equation

Tags: math, mathjax, mathml

I'm using wiris editor to insert MathML, the MathML equation is as shown in the attached image.

[image]

When the MathML is processed by MathJax, the following error is occuring

[image]

When a callback is define at "Math Processing Error"

```
MathJax.Hub.Register.MessageHook("Math Processing Error",function (message) {
   console.log(message[2].stack);  // message[2] is the error object
});
```

It throws an exception saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
at MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook.h.mo.Augment.CHTMLstretchV (TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML.js?rev=2.5.3:62)
```

Comment: Can tell us a bit more of the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm using a wiris editor in the Chrome Browser, for Chrome, the MathML is process using MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, element]);, When the Typset is called, I'm facing this error

Comment: are you able to reproduce in a fiddle ?

Comment: Please provide the MathML code (you can see it in the WIRIS editor window using Ctrl+Shitf+X).

Comment: i can mail you the details, please share your mail id

Comment: You can send the details to support@wiris.com

Comment: The error stack indicate that the failure is in the CHTML preview.  They should probably disable that, since you are only working with one equation and there is no need to preview it (it will just make things slower).